# Time method execution in another thread and abort on timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Hi im trying to run a method async in order to time the duration and cancel the method if a timeout is exceeded.

Ive tried to implement this using async and await. But with no luck. Perhaps im overengineering this, any inputs will be appreciated

It should be noted that i cannot change the interface "TheirInterface" (Hence the name)

Code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public interface TheirInterface
{
    void DoHeavyWork();
}

public class Result
{
    public TimeSpan Elapsed { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }

    public Result(TimeSpan elapsed, Exception exception)
    {
        Elapsed = elapsed;
        Exception = exception;
    }
}

public class TaskTest
{
    public void Start(TheirInterface impl)
    {
        int timeout = 10000;

        // TODO
        // Run HeavyWorkTimer(impl)
        // 
        // Wait for timeout, will be > 0
        // 
        // if timeout occurs abortheavy
    }

    public Result HeavyWorkTimer(TheirInterface impl)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        try
        {
            watch.Start();
            impl.DoHeavyWork();
            watch.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            watch.Stop();

            return new Result(watch.Elapsed, ex);
        }

        return new Result(watch.Elapsed, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably enforce the cooperative cancellation by requiring a `CancellationToken` as a parameter in `TheirInterface.DoHeavyWork`, and turn it to `Task`... Otherwise, as far as I know, there's no clean way to 'abort' other operation running in the same process.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Good call, i'll suggest this to the interface owner.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek has the best solution. Your other alternatives are: start up a dedicated thread and abort it on timeout (which can destabilize the app domain); start up a dedicated app domain and unload it on timeout (which can destabilize the process); start up a separate process and kill it on timeout (which is the only truly safe way to abort uncancelable code).

Comment: @StephenCleary I wouldnt agree it is the solution. It doesn't solve the timeout requirement, it only solves graceful abort - So from my perspective the question still stands

Comment: @LarsNielsen Well, if the interface accepts `CancellationToken` and works asynchronously, you can cancel one [with timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194893%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [out of the box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Unforunately the interface could not be modified, so i've scrapped the cancellation / Abort and gone with a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a timer that, when it expires, cancels the thread. Absent cooperative cancellation, you'll have to call `Thread.Abort`, which is less than ideal. I'll assume that you know of the dangers involved in aborting threads.

```
public Result HeavyWorkTimer(TheirInterface impl)
{
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    Exception savedException = null;

    var workerThread = new Thread(() => 
    {
        try
        {
            watch.Start();
            impl.DoHeavyWork();
            watch.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            watch.Stop();
            savedException = ex;
        }
    });

    // Create a timer to kill the worker thread after 5 seconds.
    var timeoutTimer = new System.Threading.Timer((s) =>
        {
            workerThread.Abort();
        }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.Infinite);

    workerThread.Start();

    workerThread.Join();

    return new Result(watch.Elapsed, savedException);
}
```

Note that if you abort the thread, the thread will get `ThreadAbortException`.

If you can convince the interface owner to add cooperative cancellation, then you can change the timer callback so that it requests cancellation on the token rather than calling `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately the interface owner did not want to support cancellation. And i dare not abort the thread, not knowing the consequences. So instead of calling workerThread.Abort(), i decided to raise an event signalling a timeout and notifying the user.